# How to place an A5 content in the center of an A4 page?

Tags: paper-size

My PhD thesis needs to be in A5 format.

During the review process my professor would ideally have the A5 document pages printed on A4 sized paper.

I know that I could just generate the content in A5 and then in the printer settings choose to have it printed on A4 pages. However if there is an easy option to change the outer measurements of the pages from A5 to A4 and later back to A5 (for the final print) this would be preferable as it does not leave the page resizing in the professor's hand.

So I would like to ask if there is a possibility to do something like this with a single package or command in the preambel?

Comment: geometry can do this, you can set the layout width and the paper width.

Comment: How would I set this up? Using A4 in the document class and then reduce the size to A5 using the geometry package?

Comment: Read the documentation and try it out. As you didn't give an example and your class is unknown, it is not possible to give exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did not give us a MWE to play with so I simply used a standard MWE like

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Now you can use package `crop` to get your A5 page paper centered on an A4 page paper like

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop} % <====================================
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

with the resulting A4 first page:

[image: resulting first page]

Just delete/comment the line with the call of package `crop` to get back your a5 settings ...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!