# KOMAScript binding correction destroys cropping of pages

Tags: koma-script, crop, binding

I am trying to print my A5 document in the middle of A4 pages. With the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478876/how-to-place-an-a5-content-in-the-center-of-an-a4-page?rq=1) I was able to crop the pages on A4 pages. However now I am using the `BCOR` option of KOMAScript and this messes the cropping up completely.

For this minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[
a5paper,
parskip=half,
twoside,
fontsize=9.2pt,
listof=totoc,
titlepage=firstiscover
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
% scrlayer-scrpage für angepasste Header und Footer
\usepackage[%
headsepline,
automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% layouts zur Ermittlung der Textbreite in cm
\usepackage{layouts}

% Kapitelname oben auf der Nichtbindungsseite
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\textsc{\leftmark}} 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm,left=1cm}
    \centering
    \Huge Title Test
\end{titlepage}
% Der Befehl frontmatter wechselt zu römischen Seitenzahlen
\frontmatter
% Auf den Inhaltsseiten werden 15mm zusätzlicher Seitenrand auf Seite der Bindung hinzugefügt
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

The mess then looks like this:

[image: Result of minimum working example]

So on the title page the cropping is not centered. This would not be a big deal as I don't really care for the title page in the occasions where I need the cropped version.

However as soon as the `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}` command is used the whole A4 format is lost and the document is not printed correctly anymore.

How can I prevent this from happening without losing the functionality of cropping nor being forced to remove the `BCOR` command everytime I need the cropped version?

**EDIT:** When I use `\usepackage[bindingoffset=15mm]{geometry}` instead of `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}` the layout does not jump back to A5, but the cropped A5 page is not centered:

[image: Result when using geometry bindingoffset]

Comment: You are using geometry, stick to it and don't mix it with KOMA-options. Set the bindingoffset in the preamble with `\usepackage[bindingoffset=15mm]{geometry}` -- avoid layout changes in the document - you can easily confuse crop.

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer thanks for your comment! I added an edit where I tried the `bindingoffset` option of geometry instead of the `KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}`. Unfortunately this also doesn't yield the desired result.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. How are you compiling and what is your tex system?

Comment: The compiling command is `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mwe_crop".tex`. I am using TeXstudio 2.12.14.

Comment: texstudio is not a tex system, it is an editor. the texsystem is miktex or texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry! i am using Miktex.

Comment: 1st note: `\usepackage{geometry}` already changes the size of the text area and margins. So changing the settings again with `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}` differs from the preamble settings. 2nd note: Each recalculation by `typearea` always setts the paper size again. To avoid this, you can use option `pagesize=false`. 3rd note: The problem of the titlepage is made by `geometry`. It provides its own options to differ between paper size and resulting page size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do something like you try to do. However it is not recommended, because usually the cover of a book has completely different dimensions than one page of a book, because the whole cover consist of the front the back and the saddle (the part you see, if the book is in your bookshelf).

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
parskip=half,
twoside,
fontsize=9.2pt,
listof=totoc,
%titlepage=firstiscover,
pagesize=false,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a5paper,layouthoffset=31mm,layoutvoffset=43mm,bindingoffset=15mm,showcrop,
% showframe
]{geometry}
% scrlayer-scrpage für angepasste Header und Footer
\usepackage[%
headsepline,
automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% layouts zur Ermittlung der Textbreite in cm
\usepackage{layouts}

% Kapitelname oben auf der Nichtbindungsseite
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\textsc{\leftmark}} 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

%\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
% Make a cover page before the document title
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{layout=a5paper,layouthoffset=31mm,layoutvoffset=43mm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm,left=1cm}
    \centering
    \Huge Title Test
\end{titlepage}
% Der Befehl frontmatter wechselt zu römischen Seitenzahlen
\frontmatter
\extratitle{books usually have an extra title}
\title{This is the in-book document title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

result:

[image: cover, backside of the cover, extra title]
[image: backside of the extra title, main title, backside of the main title, first chapter page]

Note, the whole layout is made by `geometry` and completely unrelated from KOMA-Script's `typearea`. If you want to change this, you have to use KOMA-Script option `usegeometry` additionally. However in this case I would recommend to reduce the `DIV` value. You should not use package `crop` in such a scenario. So you have to do the positioning of the *layout* on the paper manually using `geometry` options.

Another approach would be to remove `geometry` and do the positioning of the title page by changes of the margins using KOMA-Script features, e.g., using:

```
\documentclass[
a5paper,
parskip=half,
twoside,
fontsize=9.2pt,
listof=totoc,
%titlepage=firstiscover,% Does not help, because it only influences \maketitle results
pagesize=false,
BCOR=15mm
]{scrbook}

% scrlayer-scrpage für angepasste Header und Footer
\usepackage[%
headsepline,
automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% layouts zur Ermittlung der Textbreite in cm
\usepackage{layouts}

% Kapitelname oben auf der Nichtbindungsseite
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\textsc{\leftmark}} 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
% Make a cover page before the document title
\storeareas\maintypearea
\KOMAoptions{twoside=semi,BCOR=0mm,DIV=20}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \Huge Title Test
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage\maintypearea
% Der Befehl frontmatter wechselt zu römischen Seitenzahlen
\frontmatter
\extratitle{books usually have an extra title}
\title{This is the in-book document title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: cover, cover backside, extra title]
[image: extra title backside, main title, main title backside, first chapter]

But still: I would not recommend this. I would recommend to build the cover as a separate document. If you need to combine the book and the cover, you can include the cover at the very beginning of the book using `pdfpages`.